# Which species of Cactus is this and can I eat the fruit?

Tags: identification, cactus, edible

This delicious plant is looking at me and asking me to eat it. May I do so? And how do I know if the fruit are ripe? And will I be enormously injured if I accidentally touch a needle?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Excellent clear helpful illustrations, maybe note or include something for absolute measurement scale, eg: what are the tile dimensions; And, Absolutely avoid the spines! even very tiny ones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a barrel or maybe fishhook cactus; according to this [https://wryheat.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/edible-desert-plants-barrel-cactus-fruit/#:~:text=Most%20cacti%20bloom%20in%20the,prickly%20pear%2C%20and%20barrel%20cactus.](https://wryheat.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/edible-desert-plants-barrel-cactus-fruit/#:%7E:text=Most%20cacti%20bloom%20in%20the,prickly%20pear%2C%20and%20barrel%20cactus.), all cactus fruits are edible, but not all are palatable.  The fruits on this one still look a little green, but you can try one if you like.

As for the spines, avoid stabbing yourself with them - it will be painful and may cause a nasty injury, though they are not actually poisonous.

Comment: Yeah fishhook barrel maybe, *Ferocactus*. Fishhook cactus is *Mammillaria*, which this is not. I agree with bamboo, almost all cactus fruit is edible, but not necessarily tasteful. Try to find a prickly pear instead.

Comment: yes, looks less like fishhook variety, & doesn't look like their habit